# Div not taking up full width?

Tags: html, css, django

First time on SO.

I've searched around, only to see people say "Take a look at the parent".
My problem is a little different.

Here's my demo site - http://falconsnest.cf (Django Framework)

Here's the github - github.com/Sir-Lagsalot/FalconsNest

My problem is with the div "container". It doesn't fit the whole page, it's just oddly sitting off-center to the left. How do I fix this?

Snippet:

```css
@import 'http://falconsnest.cf/static/webapp/css/project/custom.css':
@import 'http://falconsnest.cf/static/webapp/css/bootstrap.min.css':
  @import 'http://falconsnest.cf/static/webapp/js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js':
  @import 'http://falconsnest.cf/static/webapp/js/project/headerjs.js':
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://falconsnest.cf/static/webapp/js/project/headerjs.js"></script>
<script src="http://falconsnest.cf/static/webapp/js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://falconsnest.cf/static/webapp/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://falconsnest.cf/static/webapp/css/project/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg raised" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Signin"><span>Sign In!</span></button>
  <div id="Signin" class="collapse">

      <div class="loginbar">
        <h1>LOGIN</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="prompt">
        <form action=forms.py method="POST">
          <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='6olNNouNeySQqSmiKExapeXe69tyAwZP' />
          StudentID:<br> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username"><br>
          Password:<br> <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password">
          <p></p>
          <font size=2px> Don't have an account? <a href="/register">Register here!</a> <p></p></font>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
  </body>
```

Hopefully this should make it clearer:

[I want the div to cover the whole page. It's not. I've tried changing the class and setting the width to 100%. Doesn't work, but I can do thing like 140$, but that's not elegant and not dynamic to different screen sizes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu6gK.png)

Comment: Post a minimal working Stack snippet that reproduce the issue

Comment: the container-fluid is fitting the whole page.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with that :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **container-fluid** instead of **container** class.

It is showing off-center to left because Bootstrap has defined values the container class has values and container-fluid class has its own values.

These values are adjusted according to the optimal view.

The container-fluid class has some left and right margin values defined which causes problem to your work.

Although container class has also some very small amount of margin defined.

Comment: Django being nonsensical. Can't find that in my code, only in the page source.

Answer (score 0):

One of these will sort it:
1) Add full width -

```
.yourDiv {
   Width: 100%;
}
```

2) Remove margins and padding

```
.yourDiv {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

3) check if any elements are not causing your div to move to left and not become full width

If those don't work please provide some code and a picture of how your div is placed.

Comment: Check that Django hasn't added any extra divs

Comment: Try adding "width: 100% !important;" to your CSS

Answer (score 0):

Haha, my bad. Sorry guys for misleading ya. I found that bootstrap had made the div 1570px, instead of 100%. When I turned it back to 100%, then it fit into that col-2. I realised that the col-2 was coming from another html file. Meh.

Thanks for your help!